# Debian - how to overwrite a package's file

Tags: debian, deb

I have two Debian packages with different names: configA.deb, configB.deb. Both have the following lines in the control file:

```
Provides: my-config
Replaces: my-config
```

and both provide the same content - file: config

When I try to install configB.deb when configA.deb is already installed I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive configB.deb (--install):
trying to overwrite '/home/user/configs/config', which is also in package configA.deb
```

I would like the to install configB.deb without deleting/purging configA.deb first and without using option `--force-overwrite`. Is it possible?

Comment: A package has no business doing anything in `/home` anyway. Again, the proper solution is to install the file in a package-owned location, and then have the user select to let the package do something in their home directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian packages cannot overwrite each others' files. Use something like `update-alternatives` to symlink the file to one provided by one package or the other without wrecking the integrity of any package-installed files. Or use `Conflicts:` to force removal of package A when you try to install package B, and vice versa.  As a third possible approach, a hacky workaround which I can't recommend would be to overwrite this file from each package's `postinst` with a copy from properly inside the package's protected resources.

Answer (score 0):

As a fourth option you could create a binary independent package `my-config-common.deb` which provides `/home/user/configs/config` and make `configA.deb` and `configB.deb` depend on it.